# How to insert a new line between 2 specific characters on the same line?

Tags: bash, shell, powershell, sed, grep

I want to insert a new line every time two Curly brackets occurs in a text file on same line, however I want this new line to be inserted either after first curly bracket or before second curly bracket.
Is there a way to achieve this by using sed, grep etc. commands.

Here is an example:

Before:

> Hello, {how} are you?
>
> I am fine. }Thanks{..

After:

> Hello, {
>
> how} are you?
>
> I am fine. }
>
> Thanks{..

(or)

> Hello, {how
>
> } are you?
>
> I am fine. }Thanks
>
> {..

I tried below command but its adding new line even if line in the file have single curly bracket, i want to add new line only if two brackets are there:

- sed -i 's/{/&\n/' filename | grep -n "}" filename | grep "{"

---

(or)

- sed -i 's/}/&\n/' filename | grep -n "}" filename | grep "{"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$ sed 's/[{}]/&\n/' ip.txt
Hello, {
how} are you?
I am fine. }
Thanks{..
```

- `[{}]` is a character class to match either `{` or `}`
- `&` in replacement section would the bracket which matched

To replace only if both `{` and `}` are present in a line

```
$ cat ip.txt
Hello, {how} are you?
fo{o
I am fine. }Thanks{..

$ sed '/{.*}\|}.*{/ s/[{}]/&\n/' ip.txt
Hello, {
how} are you?
fo{o
I am fine. }
Thanks{..
```

- `/{.*}\|}.*{/` is qualifying expression to match `{` followed by `}` or vice versa

Comment: I was trying to exclude some string along with the above problem. Now if line contains '{ or }' or "{ or }" it should skip that line and not place new line anywhere on that line. I used below sed command but its nor working as expected. Hope you could help here, sorry for asking again as i am very new to sed:
sed -i "/\({\'\|\'{\)/n; /{.*}\|}.*{/ s/[{}]/&\n/" filename

Comment: try `sed '/{ or }/b; /{.*}\|}.*{/ s/[{}]/&\n/'`.. here if line matches `/{ or }/` the `b` command will skip remaining code and start processing next line... ask a new question when you have issues like this... however I would also advise to learn `sed` first, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info for learning resources